# I can't update my Ipython and Examples version in Enthought Canopy

Tags: ipython, enthought, canopy

I tries to update via package manager. But it says HTTP Error 404.

I tried to mention as it  is given in Ipython's [website](http://ipython.org/install.html). Then I get a following error:

> KeyError: u'HTTP Error 404: NOT FOUND:
>   https://api.enthought.com/eggs/win-32/ipython-1.1.0-3.egg'

What should I do

---------------EDIT AFTER JONATHANS ANSWER-------------------------------------------

I am also experiencing same error for Examples-7.3-1.egg
and for  libxml2-2.7.8-4.egg

There is a high probability to have error with some other packages as well. Please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This server error should have been resolved over the weekend. Apologies for the trouble.

Comment: Thanks for fixing it. It ipython server error is fixed. I also  have server not found error for examples: KeyError: u'HTTP Error 404: NOT FOUND: https://api.enthought.com/eggs/win-32/Examples-7.3-1.egg'.  Please fix this also. Thanks for your support